# Dart cannot access cloud endpoint API

Tags: dart, google-cloud-endpoints

It's frustrating and I'm stuck here for one week and no clue how to fix it ; (

Inspired by Gerwin Sturm's great work (https://github.com/Scarygami/gdg-endpoint-demo) and I like to build the java backend instead.

But unfortunately, every time when I'm trying to call the endpoints API, a NoSuchMethodError error arise.

```dart
Exception: NoSuchMethodError : method not found: '_client@0x296594a'
Receiver: Instance of 'Dbentryendpoint'
Arguments: []
Stack Trace: #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch:1737:25)
#1      Dbentryendpoint.listDBEntry (http://127.0.0.1:3030/C:/Users/VincentZhou/dart/dart_dbentryendpoint_v1_api_client/packages/google_dbentryendpoint_v1_api/src/browser/dbentryendpoint.dart:162:16)
#2      main.fetch (http://127.0.0.1:3030/C:/Users/VincentZhou/dart/dart_dbentryendpoint_v1_api_client/demo.dart:24:20)
#3      main (http://127.0.0.1:3030/C:/Users/VincentZhou/dart/dart_dbentryendpoint_v1_api_client/demo.dart:64:8)

Exception: NoSuchMethodError : method not found: '_client@0x296594a'
Receiver: Instance of 'Dbentryendpoint'
Arguments: []
Stack Trace: #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch:1737:25)
#1      Dbentryendpoint.insertDBEntry (http://127.0.0.1:3030/C:/Users/VincentZhou/dart/dart_dbentryendpoint_v1_api_client/packages/google_dbentryendpoint_v1_api/src/browser/dbentryendpoint.dart:124:16)
#2      main.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (http://127.0.0.1:3030/C:/Users/VincentZhou/dart/dart_dbentryendpoint_v1_api_client/demo.dart:56:28)
```

the source code of demo.dart is almost identical to the original one (https://github.com/Scarygami/gdg-endpoint-demo) and I only change the cloudendpint API and web client ID.

```dart
import "dart:html";
import 'packages/google_dbentryendpoint_v1_api/dbentryendpoint_v1_api_browser.dart' as gdglib;
import 'packages/google_plus_v1_api/plus_v1_api_browser.dart' as pluslib;
import 'packages/google_oauth2_client/google_oauth2_browser.dart';

final CLIENT_ID = "878766780041.apps.googleusercontent.com";
final SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me"];

void main() {
  var auth = new GoogleOAuth2(CLIENT_ID, SCOPES);
  var gdg = new gdglib.Dbentryendpoint(auth);
  var plus = new pluslib.Plus(auth);
  var container = query("#entries");
  var loginButton = query("#login");
  var sendButton = query("#send");
  InputElement textInput = query("#text");
  var authorSpan = query("#author");
  pluslib.Person me;


  void fetch() {
    //gdg.makeAuthRequests = false;
    gdg.makeAuthRequests = true;
    gdg.listDBEntry(limit:10).then((l) {
      container.text = "";
      if (l.items != null) {
        l.items.forEach((e) {
          var p = new ParagraphElement();
          var date = e.date.replaceAll("T", " ");
          p.text = "$date - ${e.author}: ${e.text}";
          container.append(p);
        });
      }
    });
  }

  loginButton.onClick.listen((Event e) {
    auth.login().then((token) {
      loginButton.style.display = "none";
      plus.makeAuthRequests = true;
      plus.people.get("me").then((p) {
        me = p;
        authorSpan.text = "${me.displayName}:";
        authorSpan.style.display = "inline-block";
        textInput.style.display = "inline-block";
        sendButton.style.display = "inline-block";

        sendButton.onClick.listen((Event e) {
          var text = textInput.value;
          textInput.value = "";
          var entry = new gdglib.DBEntry.fromJson({
            "author": me.displayName,
            "text": text
          });
          gdg.makeAuthRequests = true;
          gdg.insertDBEntry(entry).then((entry) {
            fetch();
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });
```

on the Google App Engine side, I generate the cloud endpoint class automatically by the GPE and then add the client ID related info:

```dart
@Api(name = "dbentryendpoint",
        clientIds={Ids.WEB_CLIENT_ID,com.google.api.server.spi.Constant.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID},
        scopes={"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"}
)
public class DBEntryEndpoint {
.....
```

Appreciate for any help!

Answer (score 0):

The package import does not look correct, try this.

```dart
import 'packages:google_dbentryendpoint_v1_api/dbentryendpoint_v1_api_browser.dart' as gdglib;
import 'packages:google_plus_v1_api/plus_v1_api_browser.dart' as pluslib;
import 'packages:google_oauth2_client/google_oauth2_browser.dart';
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. but it doesn't work ; ( But I found a strange thing:  When you access: [orginal](https://gdg-endpoint-demo.appspot.com/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis/gdgdemo/v1/rest), you can find there are schemas and resources, but if you access [myApp](https://cloudsmart9.appspot.com/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis/dbentryendpoint/v1/rest), there are schemas and methods, not resources! when generate the dart client, the resources.dart under /common is an empty file! Does this is the cause?

Comment: for my application, I just use the default when generating the cloud endpoints class, so the method name is: listDBEntry(), and I found the mathod name is Gerwin's example is :entries.list. why need define the entries path? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figure out the way to work around it but I don't know why:

1. the "generate cloud endpoints" of GPE doesn't generate the path,
   for example it generate the method listEntities, not entities.list
2. the path is necessary to generate resource in
       _ah/api/discovery/v1/apis/dbentryendpoint/v1/rest; without path ,there is only schemas and methods, not schemas and resources
3. without resources, the Dart client generator only export empty
       resouces.dart under /commom folder.  and the mothods will be inside
       entityEndpoints.dart, which cannot correctly recognize the
       _client(), which is defined in client.dart under /common.

So the demo.dart cannot find the method.

Question: why the path is ncessary? because GPE dont generate the path automatically, can we have a way to generate the correct dart client file without manually adding the path in google app engine file? Thanks.

Comment: Could you maybe share the discovery document? Because the generator should actually be able to handle methods without resources, so there might be a bug in there.

Comment: sure. here you go  https://cloudsmart9.appspot.com/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis   and   https://cloudsmart9.appspot.com/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis/dbentryendpoint/v1/rest

Comment: I see that you now have resources in the discovery document, did you change your Endpoint code to include paths? If you generate the client library from this document you should be able to use `lib.entries.getDBEntry` `lib.entries.listDBEntry` etc.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change back. here is the right one. Schemas and methods   https://cloudsmart9.appspot.com/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis/dbentryendpoint/v1/rest